# NG0204 error when using ActivatedRoute in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I run into this `ActivatedRoute` error when issuing `ng serve` command on my Angular project:

```
Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.mjs:9296:15)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.mjs:9286:16)
    at providerToFactory (core.mjs:9332:52)
    at providerToRecord (core.mjs:9316:25)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:9213:24)
    at core.mjs:9041:59
    at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:9387:13)
    at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:9384:13)
    at new R3Injector (core.mjs:9041:9)
    at createInjectorWithoutInjectorInstances (core.mjs:10612:12)
(
```

Honestly, I don't know what happened. Everything was fine yesterday. Then I updated Angular and this is happening right now. The IDE is not indicating anything wrong

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PropertyCardComponent,
    PropertyListComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    AddPropertyComponent,
    PropertyDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ActivatedRoute],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

I have asked ChatGPT for advice but still can't repair it. It should list on `path: ''` list of properties, but instead, I have an error with parameters as indicated above

Comment: Remove the ActivatedRoute provider from the providers array

Comment: when i do this, i have these errors:


ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!


ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Comment: oh right, you didn't give any routes to the routerModule, e.g: RouterModule.forRoot([])

Comment: Thank you, now everything looks fine <3

Answer (score 0):

Your module declaration will need to

- Declare the `routes` and tell the `RouterModule` how to configure the routing by passing the routes into `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`
- Remove the `ActivatedRoute` from providers, unless you are providing an ActivatedRoute custom implementation.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PropertyCardComponent,
    PropertyListComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    AddPropertyComponent,
    PropertyDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // Add RouterModule with routes list
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule
  ],
  //Remove this 
  // providers: [ActivatedRoute],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

}) export class AppModule{}
```

Your `routes` can be declared as the following:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [{
 path: '', 
 component: AppComponent
}]
```

And your AppComponent has to inject the ActivatedRoute as in the following example:

```js
@Component({selector: 'app-root', template: ``}) 
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
}
```